# A good multi-level partial view (user control) stucture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

If have a filter form with multiple filter control inside like first name, last name, birth date, database name etc. Some of them need to be wrap into a control and reuse in the future, so I have something like:

```
@model FilterViewModel
<form ....>
@Html.Partial("FirstNameLastName", model.FirstNameLastNameFilterViewModel)
@Html.Partial("BirthDate", model.BirthDateFilterViewModel)
<input >//submit form
</form>
```

The partial views "FirstNameLastName" and "BirthDate" have it's UI and view model. I am wondering when I click submit, will my MVC controller function get all the fields in those partial views and make them into a FilterViewModel object with FirstNameLastNameFilterViewModel and BirthDateFilterViewModel filled?

If not, do you knows how to do it or any other good way to make it works with clean code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I admitted I am lazy before asking this quesion.
After an experiment with MVC3, I found this supported by default.
You just need to make your ViewModel into levels and use it on UI in the same structure, it works perfect.

Thanks.